# Jetty startup is slow with BouncyCastle included in classpath

Tags: jetty, bouncycastle

I'm using `jetty-maven-plugin` as a plugin in maven project. Plugin starts up in 2-4 seconds, but when i include `org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.52` as a dependency, the startup time is increased to ~35-60 seconds. What's happening in the background and how can I fix this?

Comment: Interestingly that doesn't happen with tomcat7-maven-plugin

Comment: probably classpath scanning related

Comment: metadata-complete=true inside web.xml didn't help.

Comment: `metadata-complete` has no meaning for scan yes/no in Servlet 3.x - all classes *must be scanned* for compliance.

Comment: tomcat7 also implements servlet 3.0 spec, but it doesn't take that long.

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Avoid_slow_deployment page says that metadata-complete must be set true to avoid scanning.

Comment: wiki.eclipse.org is for older Jetty 7 & Jetty 8 (now EOL).  use https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/ for Jetty 9 forward.  Also, `metadata-complete` now means "don't use scan results". Scan has to occur because of `ServletContainerInitializer` requirements.

Comment: That was a great info for me, very thank you.

Comment: Still I have a question, why tomcat7 isn't taking that much time, while jetty 8 and 9 do?

Comment: Tomcat 7 is equivalent to Jetty 5 in feature/support set.  You are comparing such vastly different feature sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally could avoid unnecessary scanning by excluding BC inside `jetty-web.xml`:

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Call name="setAttribute">
        <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.WebInfIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
        <Arg>^((?!bcprov).)*$</Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

with plugin configuration:

```
<contextXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml</contextXml>
```

Answer (score 3):

This addition in the web.xml solve my slow startup

```
    <absolute-ordering>
        <name>dummy</name>
    </absolute-ordering>
```